# krb command not working in ksh script

Tags: rhel, ksh, kerberos

On a RedHat 7, when I run the following command to get a Kerberos ticket:

```
krb my_user
```

It sends back :

```
Ticket for 'my_user' is valid until 08:36 (28/01)
```

Now I need to run this command from a script.
Without changing directory, I create a ksh script with the following content:

```
#!/bin/ksh
krb my_user
```

When I execute the script, I have the following error:

```
./script.ksh[2]: krb: not found [No such file or directory]
```

I don't understand where this `krb` command is found when I execute it directly from command line.

The `krb` command is not in the aliases when I list them.

If I run a `locate krb` it doesn't return anything just called `krb`.

If I run `which krb` it says

```
/usr/bin/which: no krb in (/usr/java/default/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin)
```

What should I do to make this krb command work from my script?

Comment: What’s the result of `type krb`? Odds are it’s an alias or a function.

Comment: `type krb` returns `krb is a function krb () { ...`. So this is a function. Now I have to find out what a function is in Linux context. Thx @bxm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A shell function that is available at the shell prompt is not automatically available to a script called from that shell.

There are two high level ways to get access.

- Source the script that sets up the function.  Before you do this you would want to have a really good idea of what else this script is doing; without some local knowledge I can't recommend this as a safe option.
- Export the function.

In simplest terms, you could achieve the latter option like so:

```
$ export -f krb
$ yourscript.sh
```

You would be better off adding the `export` command to your shell profile, such that it will be executed at login.

Comment: Second option works fine. But I finally used the first option as my script had to execute itself from crontab, I couldn't manually do the `export` before executing the script. The function was defined in my .bashrc file. Thx for your help :)